# View number and sizes of SSTables in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I would like to see the state of the LSM-tree for a table in Cassandra.

Is there a way of viewing the number of SSTables, as well as their sizes, at any given time point, for a given table?

Thanks!
Niv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for [nodetool tablestats](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.x/cassandra/tools/toolsTablestats.html?scroll=toolsTablestats__description_unique_41). In v2.x you can use it as nodetool cfstats.

You can know the number of sstables for a given column family and the total space occupied (not per sstable).

If you really want to know the size of each sstable, I recommend you can do a `df` command on each of the nodes at the appropriate location.

eg:

`df data\data\mykeyspace\users-5142a090078311e6be2a4b16b6b13564
 df data\data\mykeyspace\users-63f08f8115c111e699dbd9af33ffd299`

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, these tips help. I will try out as you say!